# EditorFor() que deberían estar vacíos traen información - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, model

tengo una vista que contiene dos vistas parciales, uno contiene un formulario de búsqueda y otra vista con dos campos, uno captura la hora y el otro fecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando cargo mi proyecto aparece como muestra la primera imagen(con información), pero debería cargarse como lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ya que los campos no deberían tener información.

mis modelos serían los siguientes:

```
    public class ModeloFechaHora
    {
        public MostrarFechaHora mfh { get; set; }
        public BuscarFehcaHora bfh { get; set; }
    }
    public class BuscarFehcaHora
    {
        [Display(Name = "Hora")]
        public string valor { get; set; }

    }
    public class MostrarFechaHora
    {
        [Display(Name="Hora")]
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime hora { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Hora")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime fecha { get; set; }

    }
```

mi vista index está de la siguiente manera:

```
 <div id="BuscarFechaDiv">
        @Html.Partial("_BuscarFechaHora", Model.bfh)
    </div>
    <div id="MostrarFechaDiv">
        @Html.Partial("_MostrarFechaHora", Model.mfh)
    </div>
```

el controller sería el siguiente:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var CargarVista = new ModeloFechaHora()
            {
                bfh = new BuscarFehcaHora(),
                mfh = new MostrarFechaHora()
            };
            return View(CargarVista);
        }
```

Comment: Indica también el Controlador que devuelve la Vista.

Comment: Listo Rafael, actualicé la pregunta agregando el controller, gracias por tu tiempo de antemano.

Comment: Pon un break-point y mira que tiene la variable `modelo_tiempo`. Seguramente tiene algún valor en las propiedades `Hora` y `Fecha`. Prueba a asignarles `null` a ver que pasa.

Comment: Y otra cosa. Por que estás devolviendo en Modelo a la Vista?. Si no quieres que aparezcan datos devuelve la Vista sin Modelo: `return View();`

Comment: Simplifiqué la pregunta mostrando el modelo con el cual tengo la interrogante, pero la vista index contiene dos vistas parciales, en una de las cuales contiene el motivo de mi interrogante, por esa razón devuelvo el modelo a la vista.

Comment: Pues no simplifiques, porque no somos adivinos. Por TODA la información necesaria en la pregunta para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Modifiqué la información en mi pregunta, con el ejemplo tal cual lo tengo, sin resumir.